# Exchange 2019 - Issues with Outlook for Mac Syncing

Tags: mac-osx, microsoft-office, exchange-2019

We've recently run into an issue that we cannot identify a resolution to.  We have a single Mac (Ventura) user in our domain that connects Outlook for Mac to our Exchange 2019.  The client was originally Microsoft Office for Mac 2021 LTSC but is now the O365 version.

The problem is the client will only sync mail every 30 minutes no matter what we try.  It can be manually synced with Send/Receive Folders but this is inconvenient for the user.  We have been through every setting on the server and in the client.

We have done the following to troubleshoot:

1. Clean install of Office for Mac - both 2021 LTSC and O365
2. Deleted the Mac profile and rebuilt it
3. Delete the Outlook profile and rebuilt it
4. Joined the Mac to the domain
5. Verified it is not slipping into Offline Mode
6. Reviewed all the server settings, DNS entries, event logs in 2019 with no errors

Are there any additional settings to review in Exchange 2019?  Is there a possible policy we haven't adjusted or are unaware of that is common?  Could this be a setting on the user's mailbox?

For reference: Exchange 2019 is at the latest CU, with all patches installed.  The OS for the server is Windows Server 2022.

Comment: How does the mail client connect to Exchange? Via MAPI, IMAP, or POP?

Comment: @joeqwerty the client connects with MAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future cases, we were able to resolve this by patching and restarting the server. After the reboot, the MAC client had no issues syncing.  Although there were no logged errors on the server side, we have a suspicion that there was a hung service somewhere that was only affecting this singular client.